# Python - Getting an Identation error out of the file

Tags: python, macos, indentation

I am trying to make a little program in python, nothing complicated, but extremely long. Just now, I modified one condition for an 'if' statement, and then ran it through the MacOS terminal, since it has a Python shell / IDLE (I don't know how is it called in english).

My document has exactly 456 lines, and the 'IndentationError' I get is at 'line 457' and here is the output :

> File "/Volumes/my usb key/MAIN_0.3.py", line 457
>
> ```
>                     ^
> ```
>
> IndentationError: expected an indented block

I really dont know what to do with that, since the last lines of my programs are all comments. If you want some code, I'll try to put it simply (and in english) for you all, but I would like to know first if it isn't a problem with running it in 'Terminal', because it is really weird.

EDIT : here is some code :

```
#coding= utf-8
#here I put a lot of variables(38), which are all 'int' or 'randint(x, y)'
#then I define some functions, which are all calculus
#here is the main loop :
while (a!=10) and (b > 10):
    function_a(a)
    c=0
    while (c != 1) and (b > 0):
        while b != 0:
            print "\n"
            d=randint(0,20)
            if 0 <= d <= 3: #commentary explaining my program for my buddies at school
                b=function_b(b, e, f, g, h, i, j, a, k, l)
                if b <= 0: #commentary
                    m += n
                    p += a_b
                    if p > 1000: #commentary
                        p -= 1000
                        k += 1
                        print " BRAVO !"
                        print " now", k
                        time.sleep(1)
                        b += b_levelup
                        e += e_levelup
                        f += f_levelup
                        print " you won", b_levelup, "points"
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print " you won", e_levelup, "points"
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print " you won", f_levelup, "points"
                        time.sleep(1)
                print "\n"*2

            if 3 < d <= 8: #commentary

                b=function_b(b, e, f, g, q, r, s, a, k, t)

                if b <= 0: #commentary
                    m += u
                    p += v

                    if p > 1000: #
                        p -= 1000
                        k += 1
                        print " BRAVO !"
                        print " now", k
                        time.sleep(1)
                        b += b_levelup
                        e += e_levelup
                        f += f_levelup
                        print " you won", b_levelup, "points"
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print " you won", e_levelup, "points"
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print " you won", f_levelup, "points"
                        time.sleep(1)
                print "\n"*2

            if 8 < d <= 14: #commentary

                b=function_b(b, e, f, g, w, x, y, a, z, k, a_a)

                if b <= 0: #commentary
                    m += n
                    p += a_b
                    if p > 1000: #commentary
                        p -= 1000
                        k += 1
                        print " BRAVO !"
                        print " now", k
                        time.sleep(1)
                        b += b_levelup
                        e += e_levelup
                        f += f_levelup
                        print " you won", b_levelup, "points"
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print " you won", e_levelup, "points"
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print " you won", f_levelup, "points"
                        time.sleep(1)
                print "\n"*2

            if 15 <= d <= 16:#commentary
                a_c += 1
                function_c()

            if d == 17: #commentary
                a_d += 1
                function_d()

            #boss commentary
            if (d == 18) and (a_d == 0):
                print " mkay"
                time.sleep(2)
                print " nope"
                print " next door"

            #commentary
            if (d == 18) and (a_d >= 1):
                print " arrived"
                time.sleep(2)
                print " wanna go ?"
                print " yes - 1"
                print " No - any other"
                a_e=input(" ")
                if a_e == 1:
                    #boss commentary
```

Comment: Make sure you're using *only* tabs or *only* spaces, not a combination of the two.

Comment: We need the code for that. Most interesting or some lines before the error. If your file is `nothing complicated, but extremely long` you should consider to split it into multiple pieces? Are you using tabs or spaces? Or a mix? Be consistent!

Comment: @tuxtimo I'm using SublimeText, so I selected the whole program and then clicked the 'Convert indentation to tabs'. So it should normally be all tabs for the whole file. What's bothering me is that it is out of the range of my file. LINE 457 DOESN'T EXIST !

Comment: That means you have a dangling syntactical construct, like a `try` with no `except` or `finally`.

Comment: Of course we need to see some code. When you ask a mechanic what's wrong with your car, you bring the car to the shop, right?

Comment: @McGlothlin I'm only using tabs.and the last line is a single line, not encapsulated in any 'while' or 'if', and it is a 'print' so it shouldn't be the program considering it part of a loop.

Comment: @ThibaultdeVillèle I suggest you to use spaces instead of tabs. Could you please post some code?

Comment: @user2357112 I'm not using any try, except or finally. As I said, the program is fairly simple in terms of the commands used. Just sooooo long.

Comment: @tuxtimo I also used the opposite command ('Convert indentation in spaces'), but for the code, I'm translating it.

Comment: "Let me some time to translate/explain it shortly." - if you strip it down, make sure you actually try to run the stripped-down version, and make sure it actually produces an IndentationError. Otherwise, you've stripped out the bug, and we can't help you.

Comment: We do not need to understand the strings or variables as long as the python keywords are english - it's all fine

Comment: The code you've posted has a dangling "if" statement: there's no body to it.  This will give the indentation error.  Does that match your full program?  What is the last active code (not comments)?

Comment: @Prune This is the last line of my program, and user235112 has answered it ! I didn't know a comment was not considered a statement. (I just wanted to test something, and thought it would works if I put a comment in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments aren't statements, so when you do

```
if something:
    # Comment
```

The `if` has no body. That's a syntax error. If you want a do-nothing placeholder body, that's what the `pass` statement is for.

```
if something:
    # Comment
    pass
```